# About Spring MVC can't resolve static resource in the WEB-INF

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My WEB structure like this :

[image]

My Spring-MVC config like this :

```
<mvc:resources location="/WEB-INF/static/" mapping="/static/**" />
```

And my servlet config like this :

```
<!-- Servlet Dispatcher -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <!-- 加载 -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring/SpringMVC.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <!-- 配置启动延时 -->
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

When config like that the web project can't resolve the static resrouce , but if i change the url-pattern to '/'

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringMVC</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The web can resolve it .

I want to know why and there are other way to resolve the static resource if the `url-pattern` is not the '/' , thanks (●'◡'●)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using suffix mapping (*.something), then Spring uses just the first part (without the suffix). This is interpreted by spring as just /index in your url-pattern (without the suffix).

And hence you get 404.

Please find the documentation of Spring `UrlPathHelper#getPathWithinServlet`Mapping for better description what is being used in the mapping process:

To fix your problem in the current servlet mapping

servlet mapping = "/*.html"; 
request URI pattern = "/a.html"

Comment: I have tried the way servlet to mapping = "/*.html" , but my tomcat startup failed .(T_T)

Comment: Also make sure you ViewResolver prefix and suffix are configured correctly

Comment: The error stack is : A child container failed during start .

Comment: My ViewResolver : '<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>'

Comment: Shouldn't your suffix be ".html"

Comment: I use the jsp as the view . Not the html , i want to use the *.html as bogus static state . if i change the suffix to the .html the web project can't resolve the view page . And i haven't the html folder .

Comment: .html files are not servers side pages such as jsp's or asp (for .net). Your dispatechers servlets can t map html pages. Also, serving html from within the web-inf folder is not recommended. Store your html inside your resource folder.